# How to save the listview subitem to database

Tags: vb6

I want to save the listview subitem in table

Code

```
Dim sSQL As String
    Dim idx As Integer
    idx = 1
    With lstLVDetails.ListItems
        For idx = idx To .count
                sSQL = "Insert into sample values ('" & .Item(idx) & "', '" & .Item(idx).SubItems(1) & "') "
                RdoVisPay.Execute sSQL, rdExecDirect
        Next idx
       End
```

The above code is not showing any error, but it is not inserting any values.

What wrong in my code.

Need code help...

Comment: Please use the debugger to check what sSQL is set to before executing it, assuming it gets into the loop in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on:

```
RdoVisPay.Execute sSQL, rdExecDirect
```

Is this line ever getting hit?  At the start, `idx` = 1.  if `lstLVDetails.ListItems.Count`=1, you'll never hit the code to insert anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the case: unlike the list box control, items in a list view control are indexed so that 1 = 1st item. On the other hand, the OP should be using his or her debugger to figure this out.